# UPDATE LEFT JOIN getting last inserted record in second table

Tags: mysql, left-join

My query is

```
UPDATE xxx_tickets
LEFT JOIN xxx_ticket_comments
ON xxx_tickets.ID = xxx_ticket_comments.ticket_id
SET xxx_tickets.status = 'open'
WHERE xxx_ticket_comments.private = '1'
AND xxx_tickets.org_code = '9'
AND xxx_tickets.ID = '2'
ORDER BY xxx_ticket_comments.ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

The problem I am having is that the second table `xxx_ticket_comments` has multiple records that relate to the `ticket_id`. What I need is to join the table so that I get the last record in `xxx_ticket_comments`

ORDER BY does not work in my statement but I left it so that you can get an idea what I am trying to accomplish.

In short I need to update `xxx_tickets` based on the most current record in `xxx_ticket_comments`

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Last record with regard to _what_?  You need to give us a column/ordering to determine the "last" record.

Comment: thats why I left `ORDER BY xxx_ticket_comments.ID DESC LIMIT 1` to show you the order. The comments table has multiple records, I just need the last one based on the column `ID` DESC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the condition to the `WHERE` clause.

```
UPDATE xxx_tickets t LEFT JOIN
       xxx_ticket_comments tc
       ON t.ID = tc.ticket_id AND
          tc.private = 1
    SET t.status = 'open'
    WHERE t.org_code = 9 AND t.ID = 2 AND
          tc.ID = (SELECT MAX(tc2.ID)
                   FROM xxx_ticket_comments tc2
                   WHERE tc2.ticket_id = tc.ticket_id AND
                         tc2.private = 1
                  );
```

Unfortunately, `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` are not supported with `JOIN`.